# LINQ in SQL Server database project C# Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq

I created a SQL Server database project. In this project, I have some classes where I use LINQ. Simple syntax LINQ is working properly - for example:

```
var p =  AreasList.Where(c => c.AreaId == (int)Areas.FlowForm)
                  .Select(c => c.Area)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

but if I try group data by using LINQ, an error occurs

```
var result = new List<SPDayPerformanceByPartNumberData>();

result = casting.Select(k => new SPDayPerformanceByPartNumberData
                {
                    Cast_No_Real = k.pack_item,
                    WeekID = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday),
                    Part_No = k.artikiel,
                    Wheel_Style = k.artikel_bez
                })
                .GroupBy(e => new { e.Cast_No_Real, e.WeekID, e.Part_No, e.Wheel_Style })
                .Select(f => f.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

This data are returned to stored procedure and if I execute the stored procedure, I get an error:

[image: Error message]

This is strange because exactly the same code if I run in Windows Forms project then everything works properly.

I install to Visual Studio "LINQ to SQL Tools".

I want to know if on this type of project used LINQ syntax is supported? If yes what should I do to resolve my issue?

Comment: I do not think this is about LINQ. Look at the error message: you have a NRE. Do you need to register something with dependency injection or configure your db context or something like that?

Comment: I saw NRE and this is realy strange. If I comment below mentoined code than issue don't occure so my  suspicion is that this type of syntax is not supported. What I do that ist operation on List "casting" and this List returen  values and there is no empy values

Comment: strange. Now its working. I did nothing with code. Data was the same. Only what was done is restart SQL services. Maybe some cache was cleaned durring restart

Comment: To me, it sounds unusual that you're using C# in a database project. My database projects only have SQL, and are only for maintaining the DB schema. What are you doing ?

Comment: your group by is not matching the columns you select. if column is not in group by - you need to aggregate it try max(column) ...etc..

Comment: Have you checked that the datatypes of the grouped columns match those in the database schema and in the SPDayPerformanceByPartNumberData class.